# DC motor speed is too low while interfacing with L293D motor driver and ATmega8

Tags: avr, atmega, pwm, dc-motor, proteus

I am trying to drive a 6V DC motor with an L293D driver and ATmega8 without PWM. The problem is, I am getting a very low speed while connecting the motor via L293D driver.But, It rotates well when I provide direct 6V DC supply to the motor.

I am using an external 6V source at the VS (motor supply) pin of the L293D but there is no improvement. The motor does not rotate until I turn the rotor by hand. What could be the problem? My code is here:

```
DDRB = 0xFF;
while(1)
{
  PORTB = 0B00000010;
  _delay_ms(20000);
}
```

My simulation design is here:
[image: Interfacing DC gear motor with Atmega8]

Comment: Seems you used of the proteus program to simulate it. please testing it for real.

Comment: What about your gnd connection to the MCU.

Comment: I have simulated it. It rotates well in simulation mode. But, the problem occurred when i implemented it real.I have connected GND of ATmega8 perfectly. I am confused about unused L293D pins. Should i connect the unused pin with GND or keep it open?

Comment: Did you measure the voltage at pins 2, 7, 8, 3 and 6 ?

Comment: Check how much current the motor draws at 6V. Maybe it draws more than the L293D can provide?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what the L293D spec says: -

[image]

In red I've extrapolated what this means for a 6V battery supply. So, in  a H bridge you can't really expect to put more than 3 or 4 volts onto your motor from a 6V supply. The device isn't modern and it isn't geared up for driving 6V motors from a 6V supply.

Also note the current drive capability of the device is 0.6A which is poor for driving any decent mechanical load.